# yaml-cpp library installation in docker

Tags: docker, shared-libraries, static-linking, yaml-cpp

I want to install `yaml-cpp` library within Docker. I am able to install on my PC (Ubuntu) from this [github repo](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) with these steps:

```
cmake cmake [-G generator] [-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON|OFF] ..
make
make install
```

**And yaml-cpp works fine.**

I do the same steps in Docker. Then I start MyProject and link it against `yaml-cpp` library in CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject yaml-cpp)
```

But I have the error when I try to launch in executable file:

```
./MyProject: error while loading shared libraries: libyaml-cpp.so.0.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Update**

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  sudo \
  git \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  libboost-dev \
  libboost-all-dev \
  doxygen \
  unzip \
  python3 \
  wget 

## Install SimGrid
RUN git clone https://github.com/simgrid/simgrid.git
WORKDIR "/simgrid"
RUN cmake -Denable_documentation=OFF -Denable_coverage=OFF \
  -Denable_java=OFF -Denable_model-checking=OFF \
  -Denable_lua=OFF -Denable_compile_optimizations=OFF -Denable_smpi=OFF \ 
  -Denable_smpi_MPICH3_testsuite=OFF -Denable_compile_warnings=OFF .
RUN sudo sync; sudo make; sudo make install;
RUN cd lib && sudo cp * /usr/lib; cd ../include && sudo cp -a * /usr/include

## Install yaml-cpp parser
RUN git clone https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp.git
WORKDIR "/yaml-cpp"
RUN mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .. && cd .. && make && make install

# LHCb grid simulation project
WORKDIR "/"
RUN git clone https://github.com/skygrid/grid_simulation.git
WORKDIR "/grid_simulation"
RUN sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=500000
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

Comment: some more info about your dockerfile would be great

Comment: post your Dockerfile so we can see how you are building this image.

Comment: @ro0kie4 @gbolo I've added `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my own shared library inside docker container. By some reason my app couldn't find library even though I've put it in /usr/local/lib/ directory. In the host machine everything worked fine.

Magically, app started to work after executing cli command inside docker container that simply finds ldd search paths: ldconfig -v | grep -v ^$'\t'.